# There's no such thing as a free lunch

Tags: code-golf, string, math, number

...or is there?

Your challenge is to parse my lunch bill, which contains the base price, tips, discounts, coupons, and extras and **find out if my lunch was $0 or less**. If this is the input:

```
12.34
15 tip
25 discount
1.5 extra
2 coupon
```

Then the output might be `false`. Here's how it works:

`12.34` is the base price.

`15 tip` means to *add 15% to the total.*

`25 discount` means to *subtract 25% from the total.*

`1.5 extra` means to *add 1.5 to the total.*

`2 coupon` means to *subtract 2 from the total.*

There may be **any amount of** tips, discounts, coupons, and extras, but there will always be one base price.

Then we do `(12.34 * 1.15) * 0.75 + 1.5 - 2` for an output of 10.14. 10.14 is greater than 0, so we output false. My lunch was not free.

## Rules

*number* `tip` means to add *number* percent to the total.

*number* `discount` means to subtract *number* percent from the total

*number* `extra` means to add *number* to the total

*number* `coupon` means to subtract *number* from the total

## Another example:

```
10
20 tip
20 discount
2 coupon
2 coupon
1 coupon
50 discount
2.55 coupon
```

The price is `-0.24` ((10 * 1.20 * 0.80 - 2 - 2 - 1) * 0.5 - 2.55), so the output is true (my lunch was free.)

Notes:

- Precision must be at least 2 decimal places.
- You can take input as a string with newlines (trailing newline optional) or another separation character, or an array/list of the inputs.

Comment: Does the input need to have the name, or can we assume the order if we just input an array of numbers [12.34,15,25,1.5,2]?

Comment: @StewieGriffin You can't chose the order. There may be more than 5 rows or maybe less. You can take 2 coupon as 2.00 coupon, and `15 tip` as `0.15 tip`

Comment: Is this input case-sensitive? Is that all of the words we need to support?

Comment: @Riker that is all the words needed, and the input will always be lower case.

Comment: How does the evaluation order work? For example, if we have a discount, then a tip, does the tip apply to the original amount or the discounted amount?

Comment: Will the base price always be first in the list?

Comment: @Sinusoid yes..

Comment: Is the bill guaranteed to contain at least 2 rows? (Total + Tip is the bare minimum, I suppose.)

Comment: @Arnauld yes, it is.

Comment: "Then the output might be `false`" -- I think "Then the output will be false" would be better. Note the lack of code formatting, and the definitive statement. "Falsy" is also a word you could use in that place.

Comment: Can the floating point error be ignored? (such as 0.9-0.3-0.3-0.3 is more than 0 in some cases)?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>37</s> <s>33</s> 34 bytes

```
I|vy#`0èÇ7%`">* - (>* +"#sè.V}î0›_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@@9ZU1apnGBweMXhdnPVBCU7LQVdBQ0gqa2kXHx4hV5Y7eF1Bo8adsX//29owGWgZ2SgUJJZAGGkZBYn55fmlXAZKQDpgvw8BMMQxjDQM0VWqGdqCpUBAA)

**Explanation**

Borrows the `mod 7` trick from [Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117841/47066)

```
I                                  # initialize stack with first input
 |v                                # loop over all other inputs
   y#`                             # split input on space as separate to stack
      0èÇ                          # get the character code of the first letter of the type
         7%`                       # mod by 7
            ">* - (>* +"#          # push the list ['>*','-','(>*','+'] where
                                   # '>*' =  increment and multiply
                                   # '-' =   subtract
                                   # '(>*' = negate, increment, multiply
                                   # '+' =   add
                         s         # swap the top 2 items on the stack
                          è        # use the mod result to index into the list
                           .V      # run as 05AB1E code
                             }     # end loop
                              î0›_ # check if the result rounded up to nearest integer 
                                   # is less than or equal to 0
```

Comment: I get `1` when the value is <1.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: Good catch. The comparison apparently cast to integer :/

Answer (score 8):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>88</s> 85 bytes

Takes input as an array of strings. Returns `0` for not free or `1` for free.

```js
a=>a.map(s=>([a,b]=s.split` `,t+={e:+a,c:-a,t:x=t*a/100,d:-x}[(b||'e')[0]]),t=0)|t<=0
```

#### How it works

Each line is split on the space to get `a` = amount, `b` = type of operation. If there's no operation at all (which is the case on the first line), `b` is set by default to `"e"` for "extra".

To add the correct amount to the total `t`, we use an object whose keys are the first letter of the operation:

```js
{
  e: +a,           // extra
  c: -a,           // coupon
  t: t * a / 100,  // tip
  d: -t * a / 100  // discount
}
```

**Note**: If the bill consisted of only one element, `map()` would return a single-element array which would be coerced to an integer when applied the `|` operator, making the final test fail. But the OP confirmed that this can't happen. (Arrays of 2 or more elements are coerced to 0.)

#### Demo

```js
let f =

a=>a.map(s=>([a,b]=s.split` `,t+={e:+a,c:-a,t:x=t*a/100,d:-x}[(b||'e')[0]]),t=0)|t<=0

console.log(f([
'12.34',
'15 tip',
'25 discount',
'1.5 extra',
'2 coupon'
]))

console.log(f([
'10',
'20 tip',
'20 discount',
'2 coupon',
'2 coupon',
'1 coupon',
'50 discount',
'2.55 coupon'
]))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>42</s> 39 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
⁾_@
⁾C×
”+
⁾‘×
ḲµṪḢO%7µĿṭ
ḢW;Ç€j”µFV>0¬
```

Takes a list of strings with decimal formatted numbers
(Leading zeros *will* work, but have the side effect of printing zeros to STDOUT prior to the final result).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@ocV@8AxeQdD48netRw1xtEPtRwwwg7@GOTYe2Pty56uGORf6q5oe2Htn/cOdaoOiicOvD7Y@a1mQBlR/a6hZmZ3Bozf///6PVDY30jE3UddT1DE0VSjILQCwjU4WUzOLk/NK8EiDXUM9UIbWipCgRyDZSAIoW5OepxwIA)** - not free; or [free](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@ocV@8AxeQdD48netRw1xtEPtRwwwg7@GOTYe2Pty56uGORf6q5oe2Htn/cOdaoOiicOvD7Y@a1mQBlR/a6hZmZ3Bozf///6PVDQ3UddT1jAwUSjILoKyUzOLk/NK8EiDXSAHIKsjPQ2UaIph6pqjq9UxNYZKxAA).

#### How?

```
⁾_@ - Link 1: a coupon
⁾_@ - literal "_@" - the Jelly code for subtraction with reversed arguments

⁾C× - Link 2: a discount
⁾C× - literal "C×" - the Jelly code for complement (1-input) then multiply

”+ - Link 3: extra cost
”+ - literal '+' - the Jelly code for add

⁾‘× - Link 4: a tip
⁾‘× - literal "‘×" - the Jelly code for increment (input+1) then multiply

ḲµṪḢO%7µĿṭ - Link 5, switch: char list
Ḳ          - split on spaces (gives [amount, type] as char lists)
 µ     µ   - monadic chain separation to get a value, say v
  Ṫ        - tail (get the type: "coupon", "discount", "extra", or "tip")
   Ḣ       - head (get the first character: 'c', 'd', 'e' or 't') 
    O      - cast to ordinal (99, 100, 101, or 116)
     %7    - mod 7 (1, 2, 3, or 4)
        Ŀ  - call link v as a monad
         ṭ - tack to the amount char list

ḢW;Ç€j”µFV>0¬ - Main link: list of strings (char lists)
Ḣ             - head - the base price char list
 W            - wrap in a list
   Ç€         - call the last link (5) as a monad for €ach of the rest
  ;           - concatenate
      ”µ      - literal 'µ' - Jelly's monadic chain separator
     j        - join all the parts with 'µ's             "10",".2 tip",".2 discount", "2 coupon","2 coupon","1 coupon",".5 discount","2.55 coupon":
        F     - flatten (makes a char list, for example: "10µ.20‘×µ.20C×µ2_@µ2_@µ1_@µ.50C×µ2.55_@")
         V    - evaluate as Jelly code (the above evaluates to -0.2499999999999991)
          >0  - greater than 0?
            ¬ - not
```

Comment: Consistently outputs 0 for me...

Comment: Ah, maybe I should say the format uses decimal?

Comment: Oh. Yes, you should.

Comment: I am writing up the explanation at the mo, [here](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@8/1cOeqhzsW@auaaxsd2npkv7UD16PGffFg0vnwdK5HDXO1QexHDTOAvIe7tzzcscnnyH6VR01rsoByh7a6hdkZHFrz//9/QwMuPSMDhZLMAjCdklmcnF@aV8JlpACkC/LzEAxDGEPPFFmdnqkpVAIA) is an example of a free lunch.

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>45</s> 42 bytes

```
q~Sf/(sd\{L(d\~ci6%"1\-* + )* -"S/=~}fL0>!
```

Take input as an array of strings, and takes the tip and discount as decimals.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@19YF5ymr1GcElPto5ESU5ecaaaqZBijq6WgraCppaCrFKxvW1eb5mNgp/j/f7SSoYESl5KekYFCSWYBlJWSWZycX5pXAuQaKQBZBfl5qExDBFPPFFW9nqkpTDIWAA)

**Explanation**

```
q~                e# Read and eval the input.
Sf/               e# Split each string by spaces.
(sd               e# Pull out the first element (base price) and cast it to a double.
\                 e# Bring the array back to the top.
{                 e# For each element L in the array:
 L                e#  Push L.
 (d               e#  Pop out the first element and cast it to a double.
 \~               e#  Bring the second element to the top of the stack.
 ci6%             e#  Mod its first character's ASCII value by 6. (c,d,e,t) -> (3,4,5,2)
 "1\-* + )* -"S/  e#  Push this string and split it on spaces.
 =                e#  Get the element given by number from the mod. CJam uses modular arrays,
                  e#    so 4 and 5 get elements 0 and 1 respectively.
 ~                e#  Eval whichever string was retrieved.
}fL               e# (end of loop)
0>!               e# Check if it's not greater than 0.
```

The code which is evaluated depending on the first letters:

```
t -> ")*"    Adds 1 to the tip amount and multiplies it by the current price.

d -> "1\-*"  Subtracts the discount amount from 1 and multiplies it by the current price.

e -> "+"     Adds the extra amount to the current price.

c -> "-"     Subtracts the coupon amount from the current price.
```

Answer (score 2):

## GNU sed + dc, <s>117</s> <s>111</s> 107 bytes

Using `-z` interpreter flag (included in score as 1 byte):

```sed
s/discount/_tip/g
s/tip/.01*1+*/g
s/extra/+/g
s/coupon/-/g
s/.*/dc -e '& 0r-p'/e
s/[^-]*$/free/
s/-/not /
```

### Explanation

```sed
#!/bin/sed -fz

# Convert to dc expression (discount is just a negative tip)
s/discount/_tip/g
s/tip/.01*1+*/g
s/extra/+/g
s/coupon/-/g

# Run dc
s/.*/dc -e '& 0r-p'/e

# Convert to pretty output
s/[^-]*$/free/
s/-/not /
```

Since the input is already very close to Reverse Polish notation, it's a simple matter to transform `extra` and `coupon` to `+` and `-`, and not much more to change the percentages into multipliers.  Then invoke `dc` and produce a readable result depending on whether `-` is found (we have to negate the result, so a `-` implies "not free", otherwise 0 would be a special case that would need its own handling).

### Example

The second case from the question is:

```
10
20 tip
20 discount
2 coupon
2 coupon
1 coupon
50 discount
2.55 coupon
```

That becomes this `dc` program:

```dc
10
20 .01*1+*
20 _.01*1+*
2 -
2 -
1 -
50 _.01*1+*
2.55 -
 0r-p
```

Resulting in:

```sed
free
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>173</s> <s>169</s> 145 bytes

```javascript
i=>{w=i.split`\n`.map($=>$.split` `);t=+w.shift()[0];p=$=>t*$/100;w.map(x=>{k=+x[0];f=x[1][0];l={e:k,c:-k,t:p(k),d:-p(k)},t+=l[f]});return t<=0;}
```

There should still be plenty of golfing to do

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#LYxNboMwFIT3PoUXLOxCXEzLBvdxEYrkiODEwrUteBFIiLNTiLKa0Tc/BnYL9TqDFVN0FvWv1@LvGlkCdfJGVHOFkM5ieliDjDd5qyIcBfxIPmWeq/m1WI6fAdLljA0sjWxP52DtqyHrqsuQYRXZwLNbdTl1yzAF15h242rs8Tl6ij@Qq23vgp@C64ULd2aYloX4@iaypGgjKUp6s1MXnh6JFCXtFxyvpKAHicFrzsn@Dw) (145 bytes currently)

Try it out:

```html
<script>var _=i=>{w=i.split('\n').map($=>$.split(' '));t=+w.shift()[0];p=$=>t*$/100;w.map(x=>{k=+x[0];f=x[1][0];t+=f=='e'&&k||f=='c'&&(-k)||f=='t'&&p(k)||f=='d'&&(-p(k))});return t<=0;}</script>
<textarea oninput="document.querySelector('pre').innerText=_(this.value)"></textarea>
<pre></pre>
```

Thanks to programmer5000 for all his golfing advice

Comment: Why is node required?

Comment: Also, you can do `{w=i.split\`<nl>\`` where <nl> is a literal newline

Comment: Node is not required. I just used it for testing on TIO

Comment: I added a stack snippet for trying it out. Feel free to rollback if you don't like it.

Comment: I am getting errors when testing it there (f is not a function).

Comment: You can remove the `f=` part, it is allowed by the rules, and you can replace `$.split(' ')` with `$.split\` \``.

Comment: I didn't know you don't need the brackets when using backticks. Pretty useful.

Comment: Fixed the errors. Replace `i=>{` with `i=>`, and `;return t<=0;}` with `,t<=0` to save a few bytes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57857/discussion-between-alberto-rivera-and-programmer5000).

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 97 <s>107</s>

Input as a multiline string with a trailing newline.

```js
t=>t.replace(/(\S+) ?(.*)?\n/g,(x,d,b)=>t-=b>'t'?-t*d/100:b>'e'?d:b>'d'?t*d/100:b?-d:d,t=0)&&t>=0
```

The regexp splits the numeric and optional text part for each line in *d* and *b*.
The calculations should be more or less obviuos. Just some note:
 - using `-=` to avoid problems mixing number with strings
 - the sum is negated to save 1 byte, so the last check is for `>= 0` instead of `<= 0`

PS still way longer than @Arnauld's. Rats.

**Test**

```js
var f=
t=>t.replace(/(\S+) ?(.*)?\n/g,(x,d,b)=>t-=b>'t'?-t*d/100:b>'e'?d:b>'d'?t*d/100:b?-d:d,t=0)&&t>=0

a=`12.34
15 tip
25 discount
1.5 extra
2 coupon
`
b=`10
20 tip
20 discount
2 coupon
2 coupon
1 coupon
50 discount
2.55 coupon
`

console.log('Not free: '+a,f(a))
console.log('Free: '+b,f(b))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 133 bytes

```
def f(b):
 t=float(b.pop(0))
 for l in b:
  v,a=l.split(' ');v=float(v);t+={'t':t*v/100,'d':-t*v/100,'c':-v,'e':v}[a[0]]
 return t<=0
```

Similar to the JavaScript ES6 version. But type conversion is required for `float` values in Python.

Explanation:

Extract the first value and convert it to float.

For each other line in the bill:

1. split and convert the value to `float`
2. Use a `dict` to select the right operation according to the first letter
3. Accumulate the value

Usage:

```
print(f([
'12.34',
'15 tip',
'25 discount',
'1.5 extra',
'2 coupon'
]))

print(f([
'10',
'20 tip',
'20 discount',
'2 coupon',
'2 coupon',
'1 coupon',
'50 discount',
'2.55 coupon'
]))
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <strike>218</strike> <strike>156</strike> 143 bytes

```powershell
($n=$args)|%{[float]$v,$w=$_-split' ';switch -w($w){"t*"{$t+=$v}"d*"{$d+=$v}"e*"{$e+=$v}"c*"{$c+=$v}}};($n[0]*(1+$t/100)*(1-$d/100)+$e-$c)-lt 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#Jc1BCoMwFATQqwT5JUYba2xdiScRKRLTNiBRzK8WrMfuOo26ezOzGBeCKaEZn5Z9T0v16PoGa5jOMJdw53boNFJCCztrlC/C5xBmtgQYBQtgXMK0Bu3m9rDarA7LzXL3uhb@pkrrKBQx4EWkKfPk0O6MQXGQjHdIUuecyJLrzVGRE9QDdTTLSaut7N8GfRJJTtQHx2ZbiG@H3tCf6bls5Ev9AQ)

**EDIT** Saved bytes by splitting the piped variable beforehand

**EDIT 2** Stored second part of string so I could make better wildcard calls

Comment: Seems to work, and your input format is fine.

Answer (score 0):

## C# <s>324</s> 219 bytes

```
bool a(string[] l){var x=0f;foreach(var s in l){var b=float.Parse(s.Split(' ')[0]);if(s.EndsWith("p"))x*=b;else if(s.EndsWith("t"))x*=1-b;else if(s.EndsWith("n"))x-=b;else if(s.EndsWith("a"))x+=b;else x=b;}return x<=0;}
```

It's not pretty, and probably not the best way, but here it is.
Requires input be passed as a string array, and tips/discounts passed as floats (`0.15 tip` instead of `15 tip`) as this has been clarified as acceptible in the comments of the spec.

Explaination:

```
bool a(string[] l){                         //Define method with input string array l and bool output
    var x=0f;                               //Initialize float x
    foreach(var s in l){                    //Iterate through lines
        var b=float.Parse(s.Split(' ')[0]); //Parse the number from the line and store it in float b
        if(s.EndsWith("p"))                 //If line ends with "p" then line is "tip"
            x*=b;                           //Parse number from line to float add 1 and multiply by x
        else if(s.EndsWith("t"))            //If line ends with "t" then line is "discount"
            x*=1-b;                         //Parse number from line to float, subtract from 1 and multiply by x
        else if(s.EndsWith("n"))            //If line ends with "n" then line is "coupon"
            x-=b;                           //Parse number from line to float and subtract from x
        else if(s.EndsWith("a"))            //If line ends with "a" then line is "extra"
            x+=b;                           //Parse number from line to float and add to x
        else x=b;                           //Line is base price
    }                                       //End foreach
    return x<=0;                            //Return x less than or equal to 0
}                                           //End method
```

There's gotta be a better way to do this, but this works at least

Comment: If you've been given tips/discounts as floats then you don't want that `100` in the `t` branch.

Comment: @WaiHaLee oops, good point, forgot to change that to 1

Comment: Tip: put `float.Parse(s.Split(' ')[0])` into something to reduce duplication. That'll save about 80 characters.

Comment: oh wow I'm a terrible golfer I didn't even remove unnecessary whitespace. I blame Visual Studio.

Comment: Not a bad effort at all!

Answer (score 0):

## Java 227 bytes

Been a while and still no Java answer that I can see, so here's my [C# answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117925/44998) ported to Java, at the cost of 8 bytes

```
boolean a(String[] l){Float x=0f;for(String s:l){Float b=Float.parseFloat(s.split(" ")[0]);if(s.endsWith("p"))x*=b;else if(s.endsWith("t"))x*=1-b;else if(s.endsWith("n"))x-=b;else if(s.endsWith("a"))x+=b;else x=b;}return x<=0;}
```

For an explanation and such, see my [C# answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117925/44998)

Like that answer, this answer expects that the tip and discount be passed as floats (`0.15` not `15`)

Comment: Pretty good...[for Java!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5829/58826)

Comment: @programmer5000 to be fair C# is only slightly less verbose than Java, main advantages being things like C#'s support of `var` generic type, and lambdas (I know Java has them, but C#'s are golfier)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), <s>129</s> <s>119</s> <s>114</s> 112 bytes

```
reduce (.[]/" "|.[0]|=tonumber|.[1]|=length)as[$n,$c](0;[$n,0,0,.+.*($n/100),0,.+$n,.-$n,0,.-.*($n/100)][$c])<=0
```

Expanded

```
  reduce (
      .[]/" "             # split each element into [value,command] 
    | .[0]|=tonumber      # convert value to number    
    | .[1]|=length        # convert command to length
  ) as [$n,$c]
  (  0
   ; [ $n                 # "" -> set base
     , 0
     , 0
     , .+.*($n/100)       # "tip"
     , 0
     , .+$n               # "extra"
     , .-$n               # "coupon"
     , 0                  
     , .-.*($n/100)       # "discount"
     ][$c]                # ... depending on command length
  ) <=0                   # true if lunch was free
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYtBDoIwEAC/0jQcQGlpTTgpL2l6QGi0BrcV2njh7dYFYwjZy8zO7uOVFJWClvQkSLD@B72dOhchLEaQvIM9yg3r/Tmv63/TcxpNHztDcq50RQmduRJ6boKD@LyaEVWiDgZu4V60k8qgzDqdi/NCAocf@SHPoJJCFKvinrM1crYlrfCtuDQipY/zwTqYEmMQh4FZ8DGgjO2buRhQvg)